# Неправильно отображается input в Safari с Iphone

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, iphone

Адаптирую сайт под мобильные девайсы. Столкнулся с такой проблемой, как неправильное отображение моего input с айфона. С телефонов на андроиде всё в порядке. В консоли разработчика отображается тоже корректно. 
Началось всё с того, что input отображался с закругленными углами. Я пофиксил это добавлением `-webkit-appearance: none;`. Теперь проблема со смещением в 1-2 пиксела моей формы. Скрин формы с консоли разработчика - https://pp.vk.me/c629525/v629525181/40c5e/zrdadYwKeBU.jpg , девайс Iphone 5s. Скрин с моего айфона ниже. Второй день уже пытаюсь решить данную проблему. Может, кто-нибудь знает, в чём проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<form id="subscribe">
        <input type="text" class="enter-email" name="subscribe-email" id="subscribe-email" placeholder="YOUR EMAIL" spellcheck="false" />
        <button type="submit" id="signup-button" class="signup-button c-form">NOTIFY ME</button>
        <label for="subscribe-email" class="subscribe-message c-form"></label>
    </form>
<!--css-->
.enter-email {
margin-top: 30px;
margin-left: 17.5%;
width: 40%;
font-size: 16px;
height: 50px;
background: none;
border: 2px solid white;
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
outline: none;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;}

.signup-button {
height: 50px;
border: 2px solid white;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 5px;
font-size: 16px;
width: 25%;
background: #32dbd0;
margin-left: -6px;
transition: all 0.4s ease;}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
color: #fff;
font-size: 16px;
text-align: center;
padding: 1px; }
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.enter-email {
        height: 45px !important;
        font-size: 13px !important;
        width: 50%;
        margin-left: 10%;
        margin-top: 8px !important;
        border-radius: 0;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
    }
    .signup-button {
        height: 45px !important;
        font-size: 12px !important;
        width: 30%;
        margin-left: -6px;
    }
    ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 13px;
        text-align: center;
        padding-bottom: 3px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Можно увидеть саму страницу?

Comment: @mJeevas коммерческий проект. Могу предоставить только изображение.

Comment: Тогда создайте полностью воспроизводимый пример, который будет отображаться правильно хотя-бы в десктопных браузерах, без всех там коммерческих частей. Сейчас ваш пример у меня отображается даже не так, как вы показываете.

Comment: @mJeevas http://codepen.io/Zharkov/pen/WwJQwx . Смотрел с телефона. Проблема повторяется

Comment: По прежнему дублирование стилей в элементарную html страничку дает некорректный результат. Как вариант попробуйте отказаться от использования button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Удалось повторить вашу проблему в safari на ios, стало корректно отображаться после обнуления `padding` и `margin`

```
button, input {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Демо: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/grzPEv

```css
body {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .50);
  ;
}
button,
input {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.enter-email {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 17.5%;
  width: 40%;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 50px;
  background: none;
  border: 2px solid white;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.signup-button {
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 25%;
  background: #32dbd0;
  margin-left: -6px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .enter-email {
    height: 45px !important;
    font-size: 13px !important;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-top: 8px !important;
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
  }
  .signup-button {
    height: 45px !important;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    width: 30%;
    margin-left: -6px;
  }
  ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="subscribe">
  <input type="text" class="enter-email" name="subscribe-email" id="subscribe-email" placeholder="YOUR EMAIL" spellcheck="false" />
  <button type="submit" id="signup-button" class="signup-button c-form">NOTIFY ME</button>
  <label for="subscribe-email" class="subscribe-message c-form"></label>
</form>
```

Привяжете правило к нужным элементам сами.

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Где же вы раньше были?) Пришлось другим способом решать, через бутстраповские стили.

Comment: Мимо проходил )